# How to adjust this table to keep the text from going to the next cell

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[htbp]

    \caption{Experimental Set}
    \label{par1}
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|
                      p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
        \hline
         {Experiments} & {No. Of Activities} &  {No. Of Resources} &  
         {No. Of Skills } &{Max. No. of Pred. \& Succ.} &{Task Duration} &
         {Max.Resources per Skill} & {Max.Resources per Task} \\
        \hline
        {Experiment 1} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
         Experiment 2 & 30 &10&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\ \hline
         Experiment 3& 15 &15&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\ \hline 
        {Experiment 4} & {15} & 10& 2& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 5} & {15} & 10& 4& 2,2&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 6} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-15&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 7} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&1&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 8} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&5 \\  \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Why did you encase all entries in the header row and most of the entries in the left-hand column in curly braces?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 12):

Your table is *far* too big. Really. Take a look at [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134574) for some options.

It's a really bad idea to use `adjustbox` or `resizebox` or something similar to make the table fit in the page, the whole thing will look weird because the font will be far too small. Usually you'll find a better approach than rescaling the table.

For this answer I modified your table completely. I noticed that you have something like a “reference” experiment, then you change one parameter in each experiment. Sorry to say this, but your table wasn't showing this to the reader, it was just throwing a bunch of apparently random numbers.

First I transposed your table so that the parameters, which are what make your table so wide, are in one single columns, using about 7 times (!) less space.

Then I removed all the parameters which are kept constant and replaced them by a `\same` command, which I defined as `---`, but you can change it to whatever you like.

Finally, I removed the vertical rules of your table because they looked strange.

The table now looks like this:

> [image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\same{---}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Experimental Set}
  \label{par1}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l *{8}{c}}
  \toprule
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Experiment}\\
  \cmidrule{2-9}
                               & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     & 6     & 7     & 8     \\
  \midrule
    No. of Activities          & 15    & 30    & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same \\
    No. of Resources           & 10    & \same & 15    & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same \\
    No. of Skills              & 4     & \same & \same & 2     & \same & \same & \same & \same \\
    Max. No. of Pred. \& Succ. & 3,3   & \same & \same & \same & 2,2   & \same & \same & \same \\
    Task Duration              & 1--10 & \same & \same & \same & \same & 1--15 & \same & \same \\
    Max. Resources per Skill   & 3     & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same & 1     & \same \\
    Max. Resources per Task    & 10    & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same & \same & 5     \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can rotate the headers:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\newcommand\RB[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{Experimental Set}\label{par1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *7c @{}} \toprule
Experiments & \RB{No. Of Activities} &  \RB{No. Of Resources} &  
         \RB{No. Of Skills } &\RB{Max. No. of Pred. \& Succ.} &\RB{Task Duration} &
         \RB{Max.Resources per Skill} & \RB{Max.Resources per Task} \\\midrule
Experiment 1 & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  
Experiment 2 & 30 &10&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\ 
Experiment 3 & 15 &15&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  
Experiment 4 & {15} & 10& 2& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\
Experiment 5 & {15} & 10& 4& 2,2&1-10&3&10 \\
Experiment 6 & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-15&3&10 \\
Experiment 7 & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&1&10 \\
Experiment 8 & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&5 \\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here are two solutions that do not employ an `adjustbox` environment. Instead, they employ a `tabularx` environment or a `tabular*` environment. In both cases, the width of the table is set to `\textwidth`. Observe that simplifying and structuring the header material makes it possible to make the material fit inside the width of the text block without having resort to `adjustbox`. For material at hand, the `tabularx` and `tabular*` based solutions provide very similar output; your pick as to which one you should prefer

As the following screenshot shows, I would also like to recommend that you give the table a much more open "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines and by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining, essential horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % choose page parameters suitably
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e,adjustbox}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{%
  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

    \caption{OP's original, \texttt{adjustbox}-based solution}
    \label{par1}
    \centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}

    \begin{tabular}{ |p{2.5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{3cm}|
                      p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|} 
        \hline
         {Experiments} & {No. Of Activities} &  {No. Of Resources} &  
         {No. Of Skills } &{Max. No. of Pred. \& Succ.} &{Task Duration} &
         {Max.Resources per Skill} & {Max.Resources per Task} \\
        \hline
        {Experiment 1} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
         Experiment 2 & 30 &10&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\ \hline
         Experiment 3& 15 &15&4&3,3&1-10&3&10 \\ \hline 
        {Experiment 4} & {15} & 10& 2& 3,3&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 5} & {15} & 10& 4& 2,2&1-10&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 6} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-15&3&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 7} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&1&10 \\  \hline
        {Experiment 8} & {15} & 10& 4& 3,3&1-10&3&5 \\  \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Solution based on \texttt{tabularx}} \label{par2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l CCC cc CC @{}}
\toprule
Experiment
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Number of} 
& \mytab{Max.\ No.\ of\\ Pred.\ \& Succ.}
& \mytab{Task\\ Duration}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Max.\ Resources} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
& Activities & Resources & Skills &&& per skill & per task\\
\midrule
1 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
2 & 30 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\ 
3 & 15 & 15 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
4 & 15 & 10 & 2 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\ \addlinespace 
5 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 2,2 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
6 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--15 & 3 & 10 \\  
7 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 1 & 10 \\  
8 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 &  5 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{0.25in}
%% Now for the tabular*-based solution.
%% Let LaTeX figure out optimal amount of intercolumn whitespace:
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\caption{Solution based on \texttt{tabular*}} \label{par3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{7}{c} }
\toprule
Experiment
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Number of} 
& \mytab{Max.\ No.\ of\\ Pred.\ \& Succ.}
& \mytab{Task\\ Duration}
& \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Max.\ Resources} \\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{7-8}
& Activities & Resources & Skills &&& per skill & per task\\
\midrule
1 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
2 & 30 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\ 
3 & 15 & 15 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
4 & 15 & 10 & 2 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\ \addlinespace
5 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 2,2 & 1--10 & 3 & 10 \\  
6 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--15 & 3 & 10 \\  
7 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 1 & 10 \\  
8 & 15 & 10 & 4 & 3,3 & 1--10 & 3 &  5 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah yes, the good old driveby-shooting approach to expressing disagreement: Post a downvote anonymously but don't indicate what provoked the displeasure. To whoever executes these anonymous downvotes: Your influence on my behavior -- or on that of anyone else! -- is negligible. If you want to make the world a better place, don't act anonymously.